# How can I configure eslint in Yeoman webapp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman

I don't find the right `.eslintrc` to edit in my Yeoman webapp folder.
I would like to use double quote instead single quote.
I also try do add a `.eslintrc` in my home folder without success.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally found. You must edit the `eslintConfig` section of `package.json` in the root directory of your Yeoman webapp.
Thank you me.

**Fragment of package.json :**

```
 "eslintConfig": {
    "env": {
      "es6": true,
      "node": true,
      "browser": true
    },
    "rules": {
      "quotes": [
        2,
        "single"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you bugyt! 